# sqlQuery in R after connecting with an oracle database

Tags: sql, r, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've connected with an oracle database and I'm running a sql query to view data in R.
Code below for reference :

```
library(RODBC)
db = odbcConnect("RenataDB", uid="xxrenfin", pwd="XXRENFIN", believeNRows=FALSE)
sqlQuery(db, 'SELECT DEPOTNAME,YEAR_MONTH,YEAR_TRAN,SALES,LINE_OF_BUSINESS FROM tbl_mod_sales_trend_cata WHERE LINE_OF_BUSINESS = 'PHARMACEUTICALS')
```

I'm getting an error regarding the sql query which is as follows :

> "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT
> DEPOTNAME,YEAR_MONTH,YEAR_TRAN,SALES,LINE_OF_BUSINESS FROM
> tbl_mod_sales_trend_cata WHERE LINE_OF_BUSINESS = PHARMACEUTICALS'"

Answer (score 1):

Up front, I'm inferring the problem, since the code you provided is a syntax error in R, and *should* be erring with `unexpected symbol`. Instead, I'll guess that you have a quoting problem. The error suggests this, with:

```r
LINE_OF_BUSINESS = PHARMACEUTICALS'"
```

Notice how there's no open-single-quote before the `PHARMA`?

Try

```r
sqlQuery(db, "SELECT DEPOTNAME,YEAR_MONTH,YEAR_TRAN,SALES,LINE_OF_BUSINESS FROM tbl_mod_sales_trend_cata WHERE LINE_OF_BUSINESS = 'PHARMACEUTICALS'")
```